# Connection downgraded to http after authenticating with SSL, auth broken with HTTP Everywhere

Tags: bug, security, ssl

I opened https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, authenticated using Google OpenID, and was returned to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

When using HTTPS Everywhere, authentication fails because of this:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The openid.return_to parameter (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=46229692-b92a-4e47-9221-1bc8a2ea72c1&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid) does not match the actual URL (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=46229692-b92a-4e47-9221-1bc8a2ea72c1&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2014-01-08T16%3A28%3A08ZYkthQjdVkVBcoQ&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3D46229692-b92a-4e47-9221-1bc8a2ea72c1%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9UYcnrN8ok5c7u7N_0w6xqXecfeGurDPvv2sfif3KdJrrpG8PqSCA4TQKcw&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias4%2Cext1.value.alias4&openid.sig=l19x4Zy0MYR0EYaHgoDzk6yZKV0%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawmMuRNLMJTQVB_HNcT1Vp5FzBfvKQHXIEc&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawmMuRNLMJTQVB_HNcT1Vp5FzBfvKQHXIEc&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.alias4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.alias4=dserodio%40gmail.com) the request was made with.
```

This problem seems to be new since I've been using HTTPS Everywhere for a while and this error manifested for the first time last week IIRC.

Comment: HTTPS is not yet officially supported.

Comment: Seems to be a dupe, I don't know why I didn't find that question before, I swear I _did_ search before posting :) Feel free to close as duplicate.